# How to check that process is terminated in WCF c#

Tags: c#, process

I have a WCF rest service, and inside it I hava a execution of a Process:

```
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = "/C " + Properties.Resources.NAME_APP_IAL + " " + ...);
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"" + ...);
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        Process oProcess = null;
        try
        {
            oProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);
            bool bStep = true;
            while (bStep)
            {
                Process[] oPro = Process.GetProcessesByName(Properties.Resources.NAME_APP_IAL);
                if (oPro == null || oPro.Count() == 0 ) bStep = false;
            }
        }

        catch (Win32Exception ex)
        {
            throw ..
        }
```

The process works well,

but after it finished I get a file as result ,

my problem that the process is terminated quickly so that I get empty file !
So how can I fix it : to be sure that the processus is finished or terminated  at first ?
Also with this verify if I have a exception or the process is blocked or anything else, how can I recognize it ?

Thanks for your help and for your suggestion and advice,

Comment: WCF is a communication framework, it doesn't run by itself or deal with processes. What you ask is no different than a lot of questions that ask how to use `Process`. First of all, call the program directly instead of using `cmd /c`. The `FileName` is `Properties.Resources.NAME_APP_IAL`, not `cmd.exe`

Comment: The other question of course is why are you calling an external program like that as if you were using CGI? This is *very* slow and doesn't scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use WaitForExit. [See dotnetperls](https://www.dotnetperls.com/process).

```
   using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
   {
       exeProcess.WaitForExit();
   }
```